# Using a single service to communicate between unrelated components

Tags: angular

I am working on an Angular 7 app. I have a lot of cross-component communication happening in my project, and the components do not have a parent-child relationship.

As I know a good solution for such problems are services. Can I have a single service that handles all communication app-wide(information will be very different) or do I have to write a different Service for each pair of components? That seems like a lot of repeated code. Otherwise, if used in each component that needs to send or receive information, on each subscribe it will actually subscribe to all the information ever sent through this service which is definitely not the desired behavior.

My service looks like this:

```
@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})
export class ComponentService {
  private subject = new Subject<any>();

  sendData(data: any) {
    this.subject.next(data);
  }

  getData(): any {
    return this.subject.asObservable();
  }
}
```

Information is sent like this:

```
this.componentService.sendData(element);
```

And is received in another component like this:

```
 constructor(private componentService: ComponentService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.componentService.getData().subscribe(data => data);
  }
```

Obviously, if ComponentService is used all over the app, this will make all components(that communicate to others) subscribe to information they do not expect to receive, and do not need to receive. 
What approach should be used?

Comment: Did you think about looking into [ngrx](https://ngrx.io/)? If you have lots of state to manage across the app, it might be a good fit.

Comment: I am not very familiar with React, and as I know ngrx is inspired from there. I might take a look though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically you could have a single service with a Subject that emits an object with a property that determines what type of data it is, like:

```
{ type: 'CustomerId', value: 35 }
```

However, you won't benefit from TypeScript's type-hinting. The good thing about TypeScript is that you can declare a type alias/interface (like `CustomerData`) and then have a typed subject that emits this data:

```
private subject: Subject<CustomerData> = new Subject<CustomerData>();
```

When you subscribe to this subject in a component, you will have a typed result, instead of the `any` type, which should be used as sparringly as possible (or never).

If you're concerned with code duplication you could make an abstract generic base service and have your other services extend it:

```
@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})
export abstract class BaseComponentService<T> {
  private subject = new Subject<T>();

  sendData(data: T) {
    this.subject.next(data);
  }

  getData(): any {
    return this.subject.asObservable();
  }
}
```

So when you create new services you extend the class with a defined type:

```
type SubType = {
  name: string;
  age: number;
};

@Injectable()
export class SubService extends BaseComponentService<SubType> {
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Nonetheless, types won't be really helpful in my situation. What I send are mostly strings or numbers; that is not enough for identification

Comment: If you have multiple components that listen to the same service that emits different number/strings, how do you know what type of data it is? If you don't use type aliases/interfaces that's fine, but you should at least emit an object that describes the type of data `{type: 'customerId', value: 35}`. Otherwise how will your components know what the emitted value represents? Maybe one component will be expecting a numeric id from the Subject, and another will be waiting for an amount of money. If the subject emits 35 you won't know if this represents and id, or an amount of money

Comment: Exactly that was my approach so far, forming an object of the type you mentioned. But somehow it seemed wrong to receive everything ever sent on each time I subscribed and I felt like I wasn't doing it the right way.

Comment: Creating many services with the single purpose of emitting a subject value does seem wasteful, but usually services contain other functions relating to the service's purpose. Like a CustomerService may emit a customer id for some component so it can update it's view, but the service could also be used for retrieving, creating, updating and deleting customers and have functions related to this

Comment: Yeah, you are right! I will use the approach of extending the Service as you mentioned. It looks like the best approach for me right now. Thank you for your time and explanations!